# Jquery css() on dynamically added elements

Tags: jquery, css

I have a table with some rows which are not normally displayed (using a class with CSS display:"none";). On a button press I want to display these rows.
The problem is that the whole table is dynamically added to the page and so the code does not work.

**HTML**

```
<tr class="HiddenRowClass"> ....  </tr>
```

**JS**

```
function ShowRowsClick() {
$(".HiddenRowClass").css("display","");
}
```

I have read about using .on() for binding events to dynamically generated elements, but I can't find anything talking about non event binding. (If that is the correct term for it)

Comment: Remove css property display instead `$(".cssClass").removeCss("display")`

Comment: @Mihir are you sure?

Comment: @doniyor thanks. Please ignore my previous comment, method removeCss does not exist. `show` method would do.

Comment: @Mihir I'm thinking that `$("tr").removeClass("HiddenRowClass");` would work.

Comment: @scartag probably not, this will remove identification class from the rows which are to be hidden

Comment: @Mihir Yeah i guess so .. bad idea :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to make the display show.

```
$(".HiddenRowClass").css("display","block");
```

Alternatively since you hid it using `"display:none"` you can use a jquery function to reveal it.

```
$(".HiddenRowClass").show();
```

Comment: Thanks. This works a treat(.show()) .  I often use display:none and then display:"" to hide and unhide things. I am not sure why it doesn't work in this case?

Comment: @DavidG `display:""` doesn't work and in this case you had the `display:none` in a class so you needed the `display:block` to override the one in the `HiddenRowClass`

Answer (score 0):

How are the rows dynamically added?  And how are you binding the button click event to your ShowRowsClick () function?  As long as the button is pressed after the rows are in the DOM, and you have an event binding the button click to your ShowRowsClick() function, you should be OK.  If the rows are being added AFTER the button is clicked, then you will have to do something more complicated like having your button click function set a state variable and have your row-adding function check that variable to see if the rows should be displayed.